# Sectioning UITableView cells

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase

I'm trying to organize my tableview cells into sections from an element of the items in the list (dueTime). Firebase is my backend and each item has a child node called dueTime with a string of the time. I have created the sections and have gotten them to show up but I need the actual items to separate into them. Currently, when I run my code, all that shows up are the sections.

```
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        let tasksRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("tasks")
        tasksRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
            var dueTimesArray = [String]()
            for task in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
                let times = task.value["dueTime"] as! String
                dueTimesArray.append(times)
            }
            self.sectionTimes = dueTimesArray
        })
        let uniqueSectionTimes = Array(Set(sectionTimes))
        return uniqueSectionTimes.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var uniqueSectionTimes = Array(Set(sectionTimes))
        let tasksRef = Firebase(url: "\(self.ref)/tasks")
        tasksRef.queryOrderedByChild("dueTime").queryEqualToValue(uniqueSectionTimes[section]).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            var newTasks = [Task]()
            for task in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
                let tasks = Task(snapshot: task)
                newTasks.append(tasks)
            }
            self.sectionTasks = newTasks
        })
        return self.sectionTasks.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TaskCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
//        let uniqueSectionTimes = Array(Set(sectionTimes))
//        let times = self.sectionTasks[uniqueSectionTimes[indexPath.section]]
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text = task.title
        ref.childByAppendingPath("tasks").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if task.done == true {
            cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "checkedbox")
            cell.detailLabel.text = "Completed By: \(task.completedBy)"
            }
            else {
            cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "uncheckedbox")
            cell.detailLabel.text = ""
            }
        })

        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let uniqueSectionTimes = Array(Set(sectionTimes))

        return uniqueSectionTimes[section]
    }
```

I feel like the source of the problem is probably in numberOfRowsInSection and in cellForRowAtIndexPath. From numberOfRowsInSection, when I print `self.sectionTasks` after I set it equal to `newTasks` I get 6 arrays (equal to the number of sections) with all of the correct tasks in their correct arrays. But, when I print `self.sectionTasks.count`I get '0' six times which doesn't make sense to me. I have no idea what to do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I can't seem to find a good tutorial anywhere that explains it well.

**Update 1:**

I've also tried this in `numberOfRows`

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var uniqueSectionTimes = Array(Set(sectionTimes))
        let tasksRef = Firebase(url: "\(self.ref)/tasks")
        tasksRef.queryOrderedByChild("dueTime").queryEqualToValue(uniqueSectionTimes[section]).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            var newTasks = [String]()
            for task in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
                let tasks = task.value["title"] as! String
                newTasks.append(tasks)
            }
//            for task in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
//                let tasks = Task(snapshot: task)
//                newTasks.append(tasks)
//            }
            self.sectionTasks = newTasks
        })
        print(sectionTasks.count)
        return self.sectionTasks.count
    }
```

I get the same outcome. Basically, this way gives me just the titles of the items instead of the entire item in each array. But it still tells me that the count is 0 for all of the arrays.

**Update 2:**

After implementing the following code, I am now getting all of the tasks duplicated under each section. I would imagine I need to somehow filter the tasks but I am not sure where or how to do that.

```
 func queryDueTimes(uniqueSectionTimes:Array<String>) {
        let tasksRef = Firebase(url: "\(self.ref)/tasks")
        tasksRef.queryOrderedByChild("dueTime").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            var newTasks = [Task]()
            for task in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
                let times = Task(snapshot: task)
                newTasks.append(times)
            }
            self.sectionTasks = newTasks
            print(self.sectionTasks)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

I am running this function in `viewDidLoad()` and am getting one big array with all of the elements of each task inside. I would imagine I need to use the " "section" element from `numberOfRows` but I am not sure how. Also, the tutorials I am looking at show the use of indexPath.section in `cellForRow` but I am just not sure how to implement either of those things.

**Solution:**

I ended up changing the querying code altogether so I pulled from a local array instead of Firebase.

```
func querySections() -> [String] {
           var sectionsArray = [String]()
        for task in tasks {
            let dueTimes = task.dueTime
            sectionsArray.append(dueTimes)
        }
        let uniqueSectionsArray = Array(Set(sectionsArray)).sort()
        return uniqueSectionsArray
    }


    func queryDueTimes(section:Int) -> [Task] {
        var sectionItems = [Task]()
        for task in tasks {
            let dueTimes = task.dueTime
            if dueTimes == querySections()[section] {
                sectionItems.append(task)
            }
        }
        return sectionItems
    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return querySections().count
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return queryDueTimes(section).count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TaskCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        let times = queryDueTimes(indexPath.section)
        let task = times[indexPath.row]
        cell.label.text = task.title
        if task.done == true {
            cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "checkedbox")
            cell.detailLabel.text = "Completed By: \(task.completedBy)"
            }
            else {
            cell.checkBox.image = UIImage(named: "uncheckedbox")
            cell.detailLabel.text = ""
            }

        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return querySections()[section]
    }
```

Comment: When I see calls that take a block as a parameter, I suspect they may be asynchronous.  Is that true for the `observeEventType` function?  If so, you may be returning a count before the tasks are filled in.  (Try putting another print inside the block to confirm the order of events.)

Comment: There's a number of UITableView tutorials available, so I would first suggest getting comfortable creating a populating a tableView with static data before bringing in the Firebase aspect. The cellForRowAtIndexPath allows the table to re-use cells it's already created therefore avoiding having to alloc, init etc a new cell for each one needed. The big picture is that you need to read in your data from Firebase separately *before* trying to populate the table. Also, if you are adding observers to Firebase, each time there's an event you will need to clear your array and table and repopulate it.

Comment: I'm comfortable populating a tableView. I understand what the cellForRow does and how to use it. My problem is incorporating the sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because call to `taskRef.query...` is asynchronous. And `numberOfRowsInSection` method expects at that point that you already know number of rows that you have.

Move querying code into some other method, e.g.

```
func queryDueTimes(uniqueSectionTimes: Array) { 
    let tasksRef = Firebase(url: "\(self.ref)/tasks")
            tasksRef.queryOrderedByChild("dueTime").queryEqualToValue(uniqueSectionTimes[section]).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                var newTasks = [String]()
                for task in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
                    let tasks = task.value["title"] as! String
                    newTasks.append(tasks)
                }
    //            for task in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
    //                let tasks = Task(snapshot: task)
    //                newTasks.append(tasks)
    //            }
                self.sectionTasks = newTasks


               //IMPORTANT: reload your table here:
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
}
```

Then, call `queryDueTimes` method from the `viewDidLoad()` method of your view controller:

```
func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var uniqueSectionTimes = Array(Set(sectionTimes))
    self.queryDueTimes(uniqueSectionTimes)
}
```

Comment: As is, I got an error about the first line of the queryDueTimes function so I changed it to (uniqueSectionTimes:Array<String>) but now I don't have access to "section" in queryEqualToValue. Any thoughts?

Comment: You should request complete data set, not by sections. Or, you can request here all sections you have and store them on per-section basis, and when you got all responses - reload the table.

Comment: I updated the post to include my latest issue. How do I use the section element to actually filter the tasks into different section arrays and how do I use indexPath.section in cellForRow?

Comment: To be sure you understood me right: there is two posibilities - one is to get complete data set and split it by sections manually (if you know how). Second - is to request data set on per-section basis. Looks like you implemented the first approach but you don't know how to split it by sections. I think nobody is familiar with your data and nobody can know that better than you.